# Adding action function to UIBarButtonItem on NavBar (storyboard) ios

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uibarbuttonitem

Currently, I have a `navbar` that has a `UIBarButtonItem` and I've added an action to it. Very simple stuff here. For some reason, it never executes the function. I've put in a simple print statement in the function to see if the button is tapped but nothing is displayed.

I'm not using a `navigation controller` right now but I have read that it might be wise to use that. I'm curious as to why this is not working with a simple `navbar` and `UIBarButtonItem`. There must be a reason why storyboard is rejecting this

Function is as simple as the following :

```
@IBAction func didTap(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
   print("button tapped")
}
```

Comment: Have you attached this IBAction with the button in the storyboard?

Comment: Yeah, I have. I made sure that it was attached before I asked this question

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      //custom bar button
        let btn1 = UIButton()
        btn1.setImage(UIImage(named: "back"), for: .normal)
        btn1.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:15, height:20)
        btn1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(popHome), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn1), animated: true);

    }

    func popHome(){
        //you action code
    }
```

Comment: I know I could do it programmatically but I was wondering how to do it via storyboard. There must be a reason why this action is not being associated with the navigation bar